# add node names from an xml file into a combobox using c#

Tags: c#, combobox, winforms

Im using c#.net windows form applpication. I have an xml file which contains many nodes. How can I get the names of those nodes into a combobox. If possible avoid duplicate names.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 3.5 you can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to select your nodes.

Alternatively, or if you're not using .NET 3.5, you can use [System.Xml.XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.aspx) to select your nodes.

After selecting your nodes you can use a foreach on them and insert them one by one in that loop.  Alternatively if you have them stored in a `List<>` you can use `ForEach` for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using LINQ to XML:

```
combobox.DataSource = XDocument.Load(path)
        .Descendants
        .Select(n => n.Name.LocalName)
        .Distinct()
        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your needs without using LINQ etc:

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in my_XML_Doc)
        {
            if (!ComboBox1.Items.Contains(node.Name))
            {
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(node.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This won't compile.  (What's `my_XML_doc`?)